# Show that $\int\nolimits^{\infty}_{0} x^{-1} \sin x dx = \frac\pi2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

> Show that $$\int^{\infty}_{0} x^{-1} \sin x dx = \frac\pi2$$ by integrating $z^{-1}e^{iz}$ around a closed contour $\Gamma$ consisting of two portions of the real axis, from -$R$ to -$\epsilon$ and from $\epsilon$ to $R$ (with $R > \epsilon > 0$) and two connecting semi-circular arcs in the upper half-plane, of respective radii $\epsilon$ and $R$. Then let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $R \rightarrow \infty$.

[Ref: R. Penrose, *The Road to Reality: a complete guide to the laws of the universe (Vintage, 2005)*: Chap. 7, Prob. [7.5] (p. 129)]

*Note: Marked as "Not to be taken lightly", (i.e. very hard!)*

**Update:** correction: $z^{-1}e^{iz}$ (Ref: http://www.roadsolutions.ox.ac.uk/corrections.html)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I demonstrate the equality using the approach given.

Comment: What have you tried? This is only slightly harder than the usual semicircular contour, you just have a small indent to dodge the singularity at the origin. The method is still identical to the contour integration problems you have done before. Also, is there a typo? You should be integrating $z^{-1} e^{iz}$.

Comment: Far far?: Null. I need a full, correct answer to pore over to get an idea of the underlying concepts. (I'm using this as a pedagogical question. [Ref: R. Penrose, *The Road to Reality*, Ch. 7, p. 129, Problem [7.5]]).

Comment: @UGP Have you seen any full treatment of a contour integration problem?

Comment: No. But I'm currently reading through Ch. 7 of Penrose's book: there's a modest but useful bit of info on the topic. Plus, I have several ugrad CA books- *Complex Analysis, 3rd.* [J. Bak, D. J. Newman] (Springer, 2010) amongst them.

Comment: @UGPhysics In that case, I apologize for my previous comment. I has assumed you had some familiarity with simpler contour integration problems. We could show you a solution, but it would need some basic tools from complex analysis. Have you seen Cauchy's integral formula before?

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34436) I'm quite sure this is a duplicate of something, but I can't find the other question...

Comment: @Ragib: You needn't worry about my background. I will keep the response as a record for perusal as I learn the subject more. ... (However, cursorily, I've encountered the concept- albeit in a *very sketchy* manner - in Penrose's book.)

Comment: Ah, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248) it is!

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! :) -cheers

Comment: @UGP Penrose's book is a very interesting book, but it is not really a good resource to actually learn the basics of any topic, it is more like an appetizer or a menu with samples.

Comment: Yup! :) ... I'm using it to appetize my tummy. :) ... Once I finish the chapter I plan on using the standard textbooks I have.

Comment: @Asaf: I don't think that this is a duplicate.  That question asks specifically to solve it _without_ contour integration, whereas this question is asking specifically for contour integration.

Comment: @Eric There are different solutions in answers there, I believe (and yes, maybe that question should be edited).

Comment: @Grigory:  There is no (non-deleted) solution with complex analysis on that thread.  This is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: I voted to reopen for the same reasons as Eric.

Comment: Ditto Theo and Eric.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294490/339790

Answer (score 7):

What follows is a proof of how to use contour integration to get your identity.

First, we want to change $\sin x$ into $e^{ix}$.  Notice that $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_{-R}^\epsilon \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz+\int_{\epsilon}^R \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\right).$$  The reason we put int the limit is because the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$ does not converge.  Now, consider the semi circle or radius $R$ in the upper half plane, and modify it by going around a semi circle of radius $\epsilon<R$ in the upper half plane to avoid the point $0$.  Call this countour $\Gamma_{R,\epsilon}$.  Also, let $C_\epsilon^+$ denote the semi circle of radius $\epsilon$ in the upper half plane. Then by using [Jordans Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) we can show that $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_{-R}^\epsilon \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz+\int_{\epsilon}^R \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\right)=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left(\int_{\Gamma_{R,\epsilon}} \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz-\int_{C_\epsilon^+}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\right).$$  Now, using the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and the fractional residue theorem we see that the right hand side above equals $\pi i$.  Hence $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Hope that helps,