# How to solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

The hint is to use integration by parts, but I really don't see how to integrate by parts here.

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^3 x}{x^3}dx$$

This is a question from a complex analysis class, so I thought I would use something like semicircular contour.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34436/evaluating-the-contour-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin3xx3-math?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link... that helped. My professor wants me to use integration by parts though. Any idea how to do it this way?

Comment: The linked question includes an answer using integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that $\sin^3x=\frac{1}{4}(3\sin x-\sin 3x)$. So we only have to find $\int \frac{\sin x} {x^3}dx$. This can be done by using integration by parts repeatedly, first convert it to an integral with integrand $\frac{\cos x} {x^2} $